# Observer conditional continue with message

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I created an observer in 'controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index', in the code i have:

```
    if (!in_array(false, $example, true)) {

    $this->_messageManager->addSuccess(__('Success message'));

}else if (in_array(false, $example, true)) {

    if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

        $this->_messageManager->addError(__('ERROR'));
        $this->_redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'customer/account/login');
    }

}
```

in the 'else if' all works great, but in the first condition i can't see the message in the checkout view.
If i put a redirect like:

```
$this->_redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'checkout');
```

It go to an error page with:

"The page www.example.local has redirected you too many times."

error message.

Can anyone say me how can i send a message to the checkout with the less code. (I know i can do an oberver, test all the products again and do the condition to show the message, but i don't to repeat myself)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect your not logged in customer that have tried to access checkout onepage showing a message or show a success message when he's logged in, you can try this:

```
if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $this->_messageManager->addError(__('ERROR'));
    $this->_redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'customer/account/login');
} else {
    $this->_messageManager->addSuccess(__('Success message'));
}
```

Comment: It's not the same, but add a message without nothing more is not shown in checkout page, it's like you need something more like a redirect... but i can't use it